# AlphBot2 with Raspberry Pi Zero is not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, robotics

I bought the AlphaBot2 Pi Zero and I am following the wiki https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/AlphaBot2-PiZero to put it to work. I installed all the libraries pointed here (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Librarie ... on_for_RPi) and I ensure that the command "gpio readall" is working properly (at least it returns the layout of my raspberry pi zero board).

When I try to test the engines they don't work and I don't have any hint of what it could be. First I was running the script on the folder that I have decompressed it and I move to the home directory. But still does not work. I also was using internet wpa connection in my RaspberryPi Zero and I turned it off, thinking it could be the problem. But it is not either.

Does anybody have any hint of what I am missing?

Here is my gpio output if someone would ask for.

```
$ gpio -v
gpio version: 2.46
Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Gordon Henderson
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type: gpio -warranty
Raspberry Pi Details:
Type: Pi Zero-W, Revision: 01, Memory: 512MB, Maker: Sony 
* Device tree is enabled.
*--> Raspberry Pi Zero W Rev 1.1
* This Raspberry Pi supports user-level GPIO access.
pi@sense6:~/AlphaBot2/python $ gpio readall
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+-Pi ZeroW-+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
| BCM | wPi | Name | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name | wPi | BCM |
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
| | | 3.3v | | | 1 || 2 | | | 5v | | |
| 2 | 8 | SDA.1 | ALT0 | 1 | 3 || 4 | | | 5v | | |
| 3 | 9 | SCL.1 | ALT0 | 1 | 5 || 6 | | | 0v | | |
| 4 | 7 | GPIO. 7 | IN | 0 | 7 || 8 | 1 | ALT5 | TxD | 15 | 14 |
| | | 0v | | | 9 || 10 | 1 | ALT5 | RxD | 16 | 15 |
| 17 | 0 | GPIO. 0 | IN | 1 | 11 || 12 | 0 | IN | GPIO. 1 | 1 | 18 |
| 27 | 2 | GPIO. 2 | IN | 0 | 13 || 14 | | | 0v | | |
| 22 | 3 | GPIO. 3 | IN | 0 | 15 || 16 | 0 | IN | GPIO. 4 | 4 | 23 |
| | | 3.3v | | | 17 || 18 | 0 | IN | GPIO. 5 | 5 | 24 |
| 10 | 12 | MOSI | ALT0 | 0 | 19 || 20 | | | 0v | | |
| 9 | 13 | MISO | ALT0 | 0 | 21 || 22 | 0 | IN | GPIO. 6 | 6 | 25 |
| 11 | 14 | SCLK | ALT0 | 0 | 23 || 24 | 1 | OUT | CE0 | 10 | 8 |
| | | 0v | | | 25 || 26 | 1 | OUT | CE1 | 11 | 7 |
| 0 | 30 | SDA.0 | IN | 1 | 27 || 28 | 1 | IN | SCL.0 | 31 | 1 |
| 5 | 21 | GPIO.21 | IN | 1 | 29 || 30 | | | 0v | | |
| 6 | 22 | GPIO.22 | IN | 0 | 31 || 32 | 0 | IN | GPIO.26 | 26 | 12 |
| 13 | 23 | GPIO.23 | IN | 0 | 33 || 34 | | | 0v | | |
| 19 | 24 | GPIO.24 | IN | 1 | 35 || 36 | 1 | IN | GPIO.27 | 27 | 16 |
| 26 | 25 | GPIO.25 | IN | 0 | 37 || 38 | 0 | IN | GPIO.28 | 28 | 20 |
| | | 0v | | | 39 || 40 | 0 | IN | GPIO.29 | 29 | 21 |
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+----++----+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
| BCM | wPi | Name | Mode | V | Physical | V | Mode | Name | wPi | BCM |
+-----+-----+---------+------+---+-Pi ZeroW-+---+------+---------+-----+-----+
```

Thanks,
Felipe

Comment: "don't work" is not a great description of the error.

Comment: I agree with you. But the python script does not show any error. The gpio lib is working correctly. The wiki does not show how to troubleshooting.... what do you think that I could show in my message to help find a solution?

Comment: Try to get it into this format: I tried … and expected … but instead … happened.